# Displaying timestamp on PHP (A non well formed numeric value )

Tags: php, timestamp

How can I convert the July 1 2055 to timestamp, if I display the code the browser will print a A non well formed nnumeric value.

Here's the code:

```
$timestamp1 = strtotime('y', $_POST['dt1']);
    echo "timestamp1<br><input typte='text' value='$timestamp1'><br>";
```

Comment: Have you tried `strtotime($_POST['dt1'])`? It's not a function that accepts multiple parameters like that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php is not `date()`

Comment: @Qirel i already edit the code, please see the code.

Comment: You still pass a string and two parameters. Remove `'y',`, try like my comment above.

Comment: I try It but the output is the whole timestamp. Like this 1507413600 I want to display the timestamp of July 1, 2016 and remove the others.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you need to do is,

```
$timestamp1 = strtotime($_POST['dt1']); //to convert to timestamp.
$timestamp1 = date('F j, Y', $timestamp1)
echo "timestamp1<br><input typte='text' value='$timestamp1'><br>";
```

will work as you may expecting.

> F: A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March.
>
> j: Day of the month without leading zeros. If you want with leading zeros like 01, 02 put d here.
>
> Y: A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

more about [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Why not just `date('Y', strtotime($_POST['dt1']))`? That is how I have most commonly seen this set of instructions written.

Comment: how can I do with the month and day?

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort `date('F j, Y', $timestamp1)`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, yes, most of the time, I just wrote multiple instructions for better understanding, just for OP. sorry this is bad code, I know :)